# C#: Build plugin/modular web application with Sharp Arcitecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, s#arp-architecture

I'm thinking about the possibility to build a "modular" or plugin-based web application based on Sharp Architecture.

The "base" application would only handle user authentication and a control panel for administrators where they could register new modules.

Then, for example, lets say we have three modules, "Customer", "Project" and "Inventory". Project would depend on Customer, because a Project needs an owner. So the customer A should be able to use Customer and Project, while Customer B only is interested in the Inventory application. These would be "installed" from the base application control panel and then integrated to the web application so users can go from the Project module to a page in the Customer module by following a link from the, for example, Project Owner page.

Each of these three modules would of course have multiple classes and UI pages.

Does anyone have any experience about this? Is there any articles covering the topic? Is it even possible to do this in a "good" way with Sharp Architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Orchard Project](http://orchard.codeplex.com/), it's a new Microsoft-backed open source .NET based CMS. It's very extensible so you should be able to build out a complex application and not get bogged down with user and content management. It gives you a good base for things like localization, seo, even multi-tenancy.

It's similar to SharpArchitecture in that it uses many of the same design principles and techniques and is built on other popular open source projects like:

- ASP.NET MVC
- AutoFac
- NHibernate
- Lucene .NET
- jQuery